# How to include git changelog in Jenkins emails?

Tags: git, email, hudson, jenkins, changelog

Is there any way to import the changelog that is generated by Jenkins to the subject of an email (either through the default email, or the [email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin))?

I am new to Jenkins configuration, so I apologize if this is a simple issue, but I was not able to find anything on the email-ext documentation.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I configured my Email-ext plug-in to use the CHANGES Token ([official documentation here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)):

```
Changes:
${CHANGES, showPaths=true, format="%a: %r %p \n--\"%m\"", pathFormat="\n\t- %p"}
```

That prints the following in my build notifications:

```
Changes:
Username: 123
    - Project/Filename1.m
    - Project/Filename2.m
    -- "My log message"
```

For HTML messages, I placed the same code within a div and added formatting:

```
<div style="padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 15px;">
${CHANGES, showPaths=true, format="<div><b>%a</b>: %r %p </div><div style=\"padding-left:30px;\"> &#8212; &#8220;<em>%m</em>&#8221;</div>", pathFormat="</div><div style=\"padding-left:30px;\">%p"}
</div>
```

Here's a sample screenshot of how it looks in the e-mails sent out by Jenkins now (this particular commit came from Subversion, but it works exactly the same for Git and other version control systems):

[image: Change list for Jenkins]

Comment: How did you know to do this?  I have looked at that official documentation page, and I don't see: 1) the list of usable tokens and how to use them, 2) where to put them ("Default Content" in the "Configure System" page of Jenkins?).

Comment: Looks like each Java class in https://github.com/hudson-plugins/email-ext-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/content is a token.

Comment: Also, clicking the ? to the right of "Context Token Reference" below "Default Content" gives descriptions.

Comment: How did I know how to do that? To be honest, I didn't know, and spent many hours searching for examples, reading documentation, experimenting, and reverse-engineering.

Comment: @SteveHHH where to add this thing?,i am adding it into content but result is blank

Comment: If there are multiple lines of commit message does this display? I tried this. It just displays only first line of commit message. If commit message is of 4 lines this displays only first line. Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: This does not address longer commit messages.

Comment: A list of content tokens that can be used can be found on the Jenkins Configuration page.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832486/jenkins-email-ext-plugin-tokens

Answer (score 20):

From original documentation:
*To see a list of all available email tokens and what they display, you can click the "?" (question mark) associated with the Content Token Reference at the bottom of the email-ext section on the project configuration screen.*

Here is result:

```
${CHANGES}
Displays the changes since the last build.

showDependencies
    If true, changes to projects this build depends on are shown. Defaults to false
showPaths
    If true, the paths, modifued by a commit are shown. Defaults to false
format
    For each commit listed, a string containing %X, where %x is one of:

    %a
        author
    %d
        date
    %m
        message
    %p
        path
    %r
        revision

    Not all revision systems support %d and %r. If specified showPaths argument is ignored. Defaults to "[%a] %m\\n"
pathFormat
    A string containing %p to indicate how to print paths. Defaults to "\\t%p\\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not in the subject of an email though you can send the change log to the recipient as an attachment in a mail using [Git Changelog Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin) as post build action in `Jenkins` Job. Select **`Create a file`** checkbox, give a name to a file (`CHANGELOG.md` for me), as in below image:

[image]

Make sure you have configured **Source Code Management** as **GIT** in Jenkins JOB.

Then create [Editable Email Notification](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) post build action and copy the name of the git change log file as the value of `Attachments`, as in below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From version 2.0 and later of [Git Changelog Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-changelog-plugin), you can get the changelog as a string in a pipeline. And then just use that variable in the mail.

```
node {
 deleteDir()
 sh """
 git clone git@github.com:jenkinsci/git-changelog-plugin.git .
 """

 def changelogString = gitChangelog returnType: 'STRING',
  from: [type: 'REF', value: 'git-changelog-1.50'],
  to: [type: 'REF', value: 'master'],
  template: """
  <h1> Git Changelog changelog </h1>

<p>
Changelog of Git Changelog.
</p>

{{#tags}}
<h2> {{name}} </h2>
 {{#issues}}
  {{#hasIssue}}
   {{#hasLink}}
<h2> {{name}} <a href="{{link}}">{{issue}}</a> {{title}} </h2>
   {{/hasLink}}
   {{^hasLink}}
<h2> {{name}} {{issue}} {{title}} </h2>
   {{/hasLink}}
  {{/hasIssue}}
  {{^hasIssue}}
<h2> {{name}} </h2>
  {{/hasIssue}}


   {{#commits}}
<a href="https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib/commit/{{hash}}">{{hash}}</a> {{authorName}} <i>{{commitTime}}</i>
<p>
<h3>{{{messageTitle}}}</h3>

{{#messageBodyItems}}
 <li> {{.}}</li> 
{{/messageBodyItems}}
</p>


  {{/commits}}

 {{/issues}}
{{/tags}}
  """

mail bcc: '', body: """Here is the changelog:

${changelogString}
""", cc: '', from: '', replyTo: '', subject: 'The Changelog', to: 'the@email'
}
```