# Jenkins Email-ext plugin - tokens

Tags: jenkins, jelly, email-ext

Hi I'm using [Jenkins Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).

Where can I find a list of all the things I can refer to in the html content of the email?

For instance: I recently found out that you can put parameters values inside the mail using:

```
${ENV,var="variable_name"}
```

But say that I want to get build log or build number or build status (passed fail).
Do you know if there is a document listing all data that is referable in this plugin.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

On job configurations page:

Check 'Editable Email Notification' box -> find 'Content Token Reference' (it's between 'Attachments' and 'Trigger for matrix projects') -> Click on `?` to the right side of it.