# How do I get the hostname into a jenkins email-ext subject line?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

How do I get the hostname into an email-ext subject line in jenkins?

I.e. I want something like:

```
`hostname` $PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS!
```

Comment: ["To see a list of all available email tokens and what they display, you can click the "?" (question mark) associated with the Content Token Reference at the top bottom of the email-ext section on the project configuration screen."](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-Emailtokens) Does anything look relevant there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10832486/1848654 mentions `${ENV,var="variable_name"}`. Is `${ENV,var="HOSTNAME"}` set?

Comment: No HOSTNAME in environment.  The hostname I want comes from executing "hostname -s".

Comment: Nothing relevant in existing email tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution :)

[image]

[image]

Tested in my Jenkins 2 instance, it's working.

Comment: Where do you get the "inject environment variables" action?

Comment: @KRichardPixley You have to install this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Comment: Thank you.

Seems like an awfully long way around the barn.  :\.