# Send Change log details in subject of email

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio, jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

I have configured email in jenkins like this:
[image]

I wanted to show following change log history in default content as text. What is the way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from this question: 
[How to include git changelog in Jenkins emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773010/how-to-include-git-changelog-in-jenkins-emails)

And Implemented like this now:
[image]